# Required text areas are not rendering the required red line correctly in Visualforce

Tags: visualforce, apexinputfield

I am having trouble with apex:inputField required="true" rendering incorrectly when the bound field is long text (textArea). The red required bar extends below the control in Chrome and Edge.  I should mention that the problem seems to only exist in community VF pages.

I have tried the following:

Using just apex:pageBlocksection with a single column, which seems to work for a backend VF pages

Using apex:datatable

Neither seem to work to fix my issue. I can come up with a workaround using CSS to correct it, but that doesn't seem like the best route.

Here is my code and below that an image of how it renders.

```
 <apex:pageBlockSectionItem >
    <apex:outputpanel >
     <table border='0' cellspacing='0' cellpadding='5' class="tableCollapse" html-eo-style-class="RegistionTable">
       <apex:repeat value="{!objGroups.m_lstFields}" var="f">
         <tr>
            <td class="RegistrationQuestionLabelCol">
              <apex:outputLabel styleclass="RegistrationQuestionLabel" value="{!$ObjectType.custom__c.Fields[f.fieldPath].Label}:"/>
               <span class="helpButtonOn RegistrationHelpBubbleOn">
                 <img src="/s.gif" class="helpOrb" alt="Help" title="{!IF(ISBLANK($ObjectType.custom__c.Fields[f.fieldPath].inlineHelpText), $ObjectType.custom__c.Fields[f.fieldPath].Label, $ObjectType.custom__c.Fields[f.fieldPath].inlineHelpText)}"/>
              </span>
            </td> 
            <td class="TARegistrationDataCol "><apex:inputField value="{!CustomRec[f.fieldPath]}" html-title="{!$ObjectType.custom__c.Fields[f.fieldPath].Label}" required="{!OR(f.required, f.dbRequired)}" />
           </td> 
         </tr>
     </apex:repeat>
   </table> 
  </apex:outputpanel>
</apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
```

[image: Text field rendering]

Comment: Which browser (and which version) are you using? Does it happen in multiple browsers, or just one?

Comment: It happens in the latest version of Chrome and Edge but seems to render correctly in Firefox.  Chrome renders the required input div at 59px and the text area at 55 while Chrome renders them 42 and 38.